# Responsive iframe height to width proportion using CSS only

Tags: iframe, width, scale

I'm trying to keep the iframe proportions always the same, despite the viewport. As long as the code below works for block units, the iframe simply does not display any content (I guess it's because the height is set to 0). How can I keep the proportions 4:3 (100% : 75%) for Iframe? I don't want to use any jquery, just simple css.

```
iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 75%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a way around. I wrapped the iframe inside the div and applied this code:

```
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 75%;
  position:relative;    
}

div iframe{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use in CSS:

For 1:1 proportion:

```
iframe {
width: 40vw; height: 40vw; }
```

For X:Y proportion:

```
iframe {
width: 40vw; height: calc(40vw * X / Y); }
```

* Any width other than 40vw can be chosen.